# Error while reading csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I am having some problems in reading a csv file with R.

```
 x=read.csv("LorenzoFerrone.csv",header=T)

Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
      invalid multibyte string at '<ff><fe>N'
```

I can read the file using libre office with no problems.

I can not upload the file because it is full of sensible information.

What can I do?

---

Setting encoding seem like the solution to the problem.

```
> x=read.csv("LorenzoFerrone.csv",fileEncoding = "UCS-2LE")
> x[2,1]
[1] Adriano Caruso
100 Levels:  Ada Adriano Caruso adriano diaz Adriano Diaz alberto ferrone Alexey ... Zia Tina
```

Comment: i never had this error before, but as i can understand from the error message you might have 2 columns with the same name in your file.

Comment: There is a solution [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Read-data-in-R-td2336018.html)

Comment: Hey you are right this seems to work   fileEncoding = "UCS-2LE". I will wait for a bit before to close the question, just to be sure.

Comment: you could post an answer rather than closing the question ...

Comment: What is your "level problem"?

Comment: I do not understand why there are levels. The results should be x[2,1]=Adriano Caruso

Comment: You have levels because the default for `stringsAsFactors` in R is `TRUE` so all your no-numeric columns were read as factors. So what did actually solve the problem, setting the correct encoding or the correct delimiter like in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the correct delimiter in the `sep` argument.

Answer (score 21):

This will read the column names as-is and won't return any errors:

```
x = read.csv(check.names = F)
```

To remove/replace troublesome characters in column names, use this:

```
iconv(names(x), to = "ASCII", sub = "")
```

Answer (score 9):

You can always use the "Latin1" encoding while reading the csv:

```
 x = read.csv("LorenzoFerrone.csv", fileEncoding = "Latin1", check.names = F)
```

I am adding `check.names = F` to avoid replacing spaces by dots within your header.

As the above not always work, another option is to use the `data.table` library along with `Latin-1` encoding:

```
library(data.table) 

x = fred("LorenzoFerrone.csv", encoding = "Latin-1")
```

Answer (score 8):

The cause is an invalid encoding. I have solved replacing all the "è" with e

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question.

Answer (score 5):

I found this problem is caused by code of file, and I solved that by opening it with Windows note, saving with UTF-8, and reopening with Excel(it became garbled at first), and resaving with UTF-8, then it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Change the file format to - CSV UTF-8. It worked for me.

Comment: this answer has been given before.

Answer (score 1):

Typically an encoding issue. You can try to change encoding or else deleting the offending character (just use your favorite editor and replace all instances). In some cases R will spit the char location, for example:

invalid multibyte string 1847

Which should make your life easier. 
Also note that you may be required to repeat this process several times (deleting all offending characters or trying several encodings).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, but I had a similar problem and figured out that it was because my "csv" file had a .csv suffix, but was actually a .xls file!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, just had a similar issue which I solved by removing " from the csv I was trying to import. The first row of the database had the column names written as "colname","colname2","etc" and I removed all the " and the csv was read in R just fine then.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing any graphical signs in the writing (i.e. accent marks). My headers were written in Spanish and had some accent marks in there. I replaced with simple words (México=Mexico) and problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but just wanted to say to non-English natives, that if you use "," as decimal seperator,