# Unable to read in csv with read.csv function

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

Ive used the `read.csv` function for years and never seen this error.

`zError in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string 10`

I have a fairly standard .csv file I am trying to read in (d[ownload a copy here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/05cmxsva5l6wenl/test_fdiv.csv?dl=0)). Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: I Think the responses in this link might help
[QUestion that might be similar to this][1]
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444769/error-while-reading-csv-file-in-r

Comment: read.csv(file, sep=",", check.names =F) as mentioned by  @Douglas Mesquita will work and you will see you have a wierd character in Cavity_Nester<ca>. <ca> is what's throwing you off.
also have a look at package janitor and clean_names function from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some on your columns might have special characters.
`read_csv` from `readr` package should be able to deal with that well and it is very fast too.

Answer (score 3):

It means that something is strange in your column names. Try to use the argument `check.names = FALSE` in your call. Also be sure you are giving the right `sep` argument.